# How to get a html-table from an sql-query with various numbers of columns?

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

I have a html-form to read out data from an SQL-database. The number of selections is completely free, which means that there are no obligatory fields.
I would like to show the results that meet all selected criteria in a html-table. Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("../files/zugriff.inc.php");

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

 $sent = $_POST['sent'];
 $datenWerte = array();
 $fruitname = $_POST["fruitname"];
 $fruitgroup = $_POST["fruitgroup"];
 $vegetablegroup = $_POST["vegetablegroup"];
 $country = $_POST["country"];
 $season = $_POST["season"];
 $diameter = $_POST["diameter"];
 $color = $_POST["color"];

 if(!empty($fruitgroup)) {
    $datenWerte['fruitgroup'] = $fruitgroup;
  }
 if(!empty($vegetablegroup)) {
    $datenWerte['vegetablegroup'] = $vegetablegroup;
  }
if(!empty($country)) {
    $datenWerte['country'] = $country;
  }
if(!empty($season)) {
    $datenWerte['season'] = $season;
  }
if(!empty($diameter)) {
    $datenWerte['diameter'] = $diameter;
  }
if(!empty($color)) {
    $datenWerte['color '] = $color;
  }

    foreach ($datenWerte as $key => $value) {
   $spalten[] = $key;
   $werte[] = "'$value'";
   }

echo "<b>Results:</b><br><br>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM fruitdatabase WHERE (" . implode(", ",   
$spalten) . ") = (" . implode(", ", $werte) . ")";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
  $data[] = $row;
}

// Numeric array with data that will be displayed in HTML table
$aray = $data;
$nr_elm = count($aray);        // gets number of elements in $aray

// Create the beginning of HTML table, and of the first row
$html_table = '<table border="1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2""><tr>';
$nr_col = count($spalten);       // Sets the number of columns

// If the array has elements
if ($nr_elm > 0) {
// Traverse the array with FOR
for($i=0; $i<$nr_elm; $i++) {
$html_table .= '<td>' .$aray[$i]. '</td>';       // adds the value in    
column in table

// If the number of columns is completed for a row (rest of         
           division of ($i + 1) to $nr_col is 0)
// Closes the current row, and begins another row
$col_to_add = ($i+1) % $nr_col;
if($col_to_add == 0) { $html_table .= '</tr><tr>'; }
  }

// Adds empty column if the current row is not completed
if($col_to_add != 0) $html_table .= '<td colspan="'. ($nr_col -             
 $col_to_add). '">&nbsp;</td>';
}

$html_table .= '</tr></table>';         // ends the last row, and the table

// Delete posible empty row (<tr></tr>) which cand be created after last    
column
$html_table = str_replace('<tr></tr>', '', $html_table);

echo $html_table;        // display the HTML table
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Unfortunately, it´s not working. Could somebody please help me to find the error?
Than you very much in advance!

Comment: What are you seeing ?

Comment: Syntax for a SELECT: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = '1' AND col2 = '2'` then add an `echo $sql;` to see what you have actually generated. Then you should be able to fix your own problem.

Comment: When I name the columns $row['id'], $row['fruitname'] and so on, it is working. However, when I use an array that contains the variable column-names, as stated above, I get no results.

Comment: based on that, should it be `'<td>' . $array[$splaten[$i]] . '</td>'`?

Comment: Thanks Jerry for your input, but whith this, I get empty fields